# iOS ota Ad-hoc distribution - Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I recently added a new devices for testing. I used Ad-hoc distribution to install the *.ipa's on the devices. But this does not work with the new added device.

Interesstingly I do not have any distribution - provisioning profiles on developer.apple.com, just one development profile, which worked until now fine. 
On my `Organizer` I could find an provisioning profile. Could be that Xcode and developer.apple.com are not in sync...

How do I get the Ad-hoc distribution working with my new (and old) devices?

> **Update**: Solved. Had the wrong provisioning profile choosen. As all profiles had the same name.

What I did (On Apple Developer Center > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > iOS Apps):

1. Added the `UDID` for the new device on **Devices**
2. On **Provisioning Profiles**:

   1. Edited my development-profile and added the new device to the list of devices
   2. Generated the new provisioning profile
3. Downloaded the provisioning profile and installed it in Xcode. (Just double-click and it was imported to the `Organizer` into Tab `Devices`
4. Created a new *.ipa file with the **correct provisioning profile**
5. Install it on the new device. // works now
6. Installing on the old device works fine.

Comment: Solved. I had choosen the wrong profile, because all my profiles have the same name. Lessons learned, name the profile different.